# During the GMEP of 1955-1968: "malaria had been eliminated in 35 countries" versus "15 countries and one territory eliminated malaria"

Tags: epidemiology, malaria

In one source, it is claimed that, during the Global Malaria Eradication Program (GMEP) of 1955-1968 "malaria had been eliminated in 35 countries".

In another source, it is claimed that, during this period "15 countries and one territory eliminated malaria".

---

*=== SOURCE 1: ===*

The MOOC "**HarvardX: MalariaX: Defeating Malaria from the Genes to the Globe**", namely in the video of the MOOC's "Module 1, Chapter 1: The Past: A Historical Overview".

From the subtitles [(at timecode 6:46) of that video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=406&v=AEPZkCaRREs):

> PEDRO L. ALONSO: First one, just to recognize as wasn't good, wasn't
>   bad -- by 1948 when the call for eradication 55, 148 countries -- or
>   what are now countries, at that time they weren't -- were considered
>   malarious. **By the end of the first attempt, malaria had been
>   eliminated in 35 countries.** So is that success or failure?

From the accompanying presentation of that video (cf. in video), the particular timespan that is talked about, is clarified. From the title of the presentation slide at the mentioned timecode:

> **Global Malaria Eradication Program (1955-1968)**.

And underneath the title:

- **By 1967**:

  Of 148 countries with malaria in **1948**:

  - **Eradication in 35**.

---

*=== SOURCE 2: ===*

[Eliminating Malaria](http://apps.who.int/iris/bitstream/handle/10665/205565/WHO_HTM_GMP_2016.3_eng.pdf), WHO:

**In 1955**, the World Health Organization (WHO) launched the **Global Malaria Eradication Programme (GMEP)**, an ambitious plan to eradicate malaria worldwide. The Programme relied heavily on two tools: the drug chloroquine for prevention and treatment of malaria and the chemical DDT for mosquito control. Over the course of the GMEP era, **15 countries and one territory eliminated malaria** (Table 1). A number of other countries succeeded in greatly reducing their malaria burden. But no major success occurred in sub-Saharan Africa and, in many settings, a failure to sustain the Programme resulted in resurgences of malaria. **In 1969, GMEP was discontinued**, but the longer-term objective remained unchanged.

---

*=== DISCUSSION / QUESTION: ===*

In the first source, there is mention of the year 1948. The second source only mentions 1955 as the beginning of the GMEP-period. My question is (35 minus 16 = 19), which 19 countries and/or territories became malaria-free during the period 1948-1955, or (what I hypothesize) which one of these sources is wrong?

Comment: Sounds like a great question for historians. Not so much for medical professionals.

Comment: @CareyGregory To what extent diseases were able to be removed from certain surfaces of the earth seems to be of great interest to epidemiologists and other health professionals interested in the disease.